# Calling function in select vs calling temp table

Tags: oracle

Just looking if there is any way to have the following behaviuour.

Currently I'm doing

```
select * from table_1 t1  where function_call(t1.col1, t1.col2) <> 0;
```

The reason why I'm calling the function function_call is , The function has the table table_2 which I don't have access. The only way I can access is through one package.

Is there any way changing the above behaviour to, having the table information in the from clause instead of calling the function_call in where clause.

like ,

```
select * from table_1 t1, package_x.get_table_2() where t1.col1 = 1 and t1.col2 = 1 and t1.col3 = t2.col3
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that calling a function from the WHERE clause may result in slow performance as this will very likely result in a full table scan of `TABLE_1`, with the function being called once for every row in `TABLE_1`.  I can think of several things your site can do:

1. Grant the necessary level of access to TABLE_1.
2. Create a view on TABLE_1 which restricts the data which can be seen, and grant appropriate access on the view, or
3. Live with the slow access times.

Share and enjoy.